# PHP Mailer fails on MS Exchange

Tags: php, ms-office, phpmailer, outlook-2010, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to send an email via PHP mailer and am failing miserably. The error message I am getting is as follows:

```
2014-08-12 12:21:40 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060) 2014-08-12 12:21:40    SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

My code is as follows. I do not know where I am going wrong with this. I am pretty sure all information is correct, with the exception of the port. Given this is using microsoft exchange I am using port 587 -is this where I am going wrong?

```
<?php
include("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail             = new PHPMailer();    
$body             = "HellooooO";

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
$mail->Host       = "My server name"; 
$mail->Port       = 587;                    
$mail->Username   = "My MS exchange email address"; 
$mail->Password   = "Password";        

$mail->SetFrom('My MS exchange email address', 'First Last');

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "test email address";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");



if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

-----------EDIT-------------------

Following Synchro's remark that I am not using the latest version of PHP Mailer, I have amended the code as follows. I am still not able to send emails and the error message is the same... How do I check whether the TLS port is open and working as expected?

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail ->SMTPDebug = 1;


$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'My Server';
$mail->Port = 587;    
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'My email address';                 
$mail->Password = 'My Password';                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            

$mail->From = 'My email address';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('My Test Email address', 'Joe User');     


$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Regards and thank you,
G.

Comment: Make sure Port is correct, usually TLS port is 465.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I changed the port to 465 and this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: The TLS port IS 587, NOT 465. That's the SSL port that has been obsolete since at least 1999. You're using an old version of PHPMailer. You're calling `msgHTML` *after* setting `AltBody`, so `AltBody` will be overwritten. The error you are seeing is most likely due to DNS failure, firewall blocking or other network problem.

Comment: Hello -many thanks for your help. I downloaded PHPMailer from here: https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer ... is this not the latest version?

Comment: **Bump** Anybody got any idea?

Comment: @Noobster We are having the same issues. I'll let you know if I resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this has been cured, however this is typical firewall behavior.  You could use something like Wireshark to see if the server is recieving the request.